# ZendFramework testing with PHPUnit can't getResponse

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I have this test code that makes an Ajax Request and i need to test that the response is valid JSON, however i can't get the response. I'm using PHPUnit 3.5.15 and ZendFramework 1.11.11

```
class ClienteControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{

    public function testIndexAjaxAction()
    {
        $this->login();

        $this->resetRequest()->resetResponse();

        $this->dispatch("/cliente/ajax/?sEcho=2&iColumns=7....");

        $this->assertNotController('error');
        $this->assertNotAction('error');
        $this->assertController('cliente');
        $this->assertAction('ajax');

        $this->assertNotRedirect();

        $this->assertResponseCode(200, 'Ajax index fallita');

        //$this->assertNotNull(json_decode($this->getResponse()->getBody()));
        //$this->getResponse()->outputBody();

    }
```

i tried to set die(print_r($this->getResponse)) and i get

```
Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase Ob
(
    [_body:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_exceptions:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_headers:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_headersRaw:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_httpResponseCode:protected] => 200
    [_isRedirect:protected] =>
    [_renderExceptions:protected] =>
    [headersSentThrowsException] => 1
)
1
```

How can i get the response after a dispatch() ?

Comment: yes why? it's not using the browser

Comment: @max4ever `headersSentThrowsException` being true doesn't look good. Does it show error messages when using the browser in development environment?

Comment: no it doesn't, not in the console at least

Comment: How does `indexAjaxAction` provide the JSON output (`return` or `echo`)?

Comment: i use  $this->_helper->json($data);